# How to get a value from JSON response to JSON request in Jmeter

Tags: json, jmeter

Long Question so Please bear with me.
I have multiple Thread Groups.

[image]

In my thread group **Create User**, I am getting a value in respose i.e **"UserId"** and this is the reponse.

```
{"CreateUserResponse":{
     "Header":{"CMMHeader": {"CorrelationId":"UserJmeter1"}},
      "Result":{"ResponseCode":"CM-N-0000","ResponseMessage":"Success"},
      "UserId":"645d026d-95bc-4782-9ad4-c034ef5f0155-1135"}}
```

Now in another Thread Group i.e **"AssignUsersinGroup"** I want to pass the value of **UserId** in its HTTP Request i.e

```
{
  "AssignUserToApplicationGroupRequest": {
    "Header": {
      "CMMHeader": { "CorrelationId": "123" }
    },
    "ClientContext": {
      "OrganizationId": "1135"
    },
    "UserId": "${UserId}",
    "ApplicationGroupId": "Jmeter1135"
  }
}
```

Now I have added a JSON path preprocessor in the **Create User** thread's group.

[image]

But its not working. Neither I can see that what has been sent in the request.
[image]

Need Help. How can I get the value of UserId from Create User's Response? and also how to pass it to the AssignUserInGroups's Request?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Here it is https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/knit-one-pearl-two-how-use-variables-different-thread-groups

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JMeter Variables scope is limited to current Thread Group only therefore you won't be able to access the variable set in another Thread Group. The solution is using [__setProperty() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__setProperty) to convert it into a  JMeter Property. JMeter Properties are global for the whole JVM so you will be able to use the value anywhere. Once set, you can access the property value via [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P)

---

A better idea would be using [Inter-Thread Communication](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/InterThreadCommunication/) plugin, this way you will be able not only to share the variables across Thread Groups but also for threads synchronization, i.e. don't start **AssignUsersinGroup** until **UserId** value is populated.

The recommended way of installing JMeter Plugins and keeping them up-to-date is using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

[image: JMeter Plugins Manager Inter-Thread Communication]